# What is the difference between Double Colons and Periods?

Tags: rust

I am very new to Rust, and the `::` operator is new to me. I can tell that `::` and `.` both have their own use cases, and I want to understand on a conceptual level where/why code would use `::` vs `.` or vice versa. Apologies if this is a really basic question!

Comment: Welcome to Rust! I would suggest reading [The Rust Programming Language](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/); this is explained in chapter 2. In short, calling `my_vec.push(123)` expands to `Vec::push(&mut my_vec, 123)`; this shorthand generally works for methods that take some variation of `self` as the first argument.

Comment: Also, you use `.` to access struct fields, and you use `::` to access module members; in general, you use `foo.bar` when `foo` is a variable (an *instance* of a struct), and use `Foo::bar` when `Foo` is the name/type of a struct, module, etc.

Comment: If you come from an OOP background, you can also think of `::` as accessors for "static methods", as other languages would refer to them.

Answer (score 2):

`::` is a path divider. It's mostly used for navigating submodules to express paths that lead to types, traits, modules and stand-alone functions (aka *items*):

```
// import everything in the collections module
use std::collections::*;

// specify a fully-qualified type without imports
let map = std::collections::HashMap::new();

// call a stand-alone function
let mut iter = std::iter::once(1);
```

`.` is used for navigating data. Specifically, that means accessing members of structs and calling methods:

```
// call a method
vec.sort();

// access a field of a struct
let bar = foo.bar;
```

Answer (score 1):

`.` is really syntactic sugar for `::` when talking about (`structs`, `enums`, `traits`):

A call to `MyStruct::foo(&my_struct)` would be evaluated from `my_struct.foo()`.

You can mostly substitute them when working with what was mentioned above.

Also, `::` is used as a *"namespace"* accessor, for navigatring through rust modules. For example for referring to a method in a nested submodule system:

```rust
std::collections::HashMap::get
```

As a note here, full submodule paths cannot be accessed in any other way with `.`.

Comment: This may be too advanced for a beginner, but autoderef may cause it to not always borrow it once and/or immutably.